# Populating an element with dynamic html

Tags: javascript, html

So I am building a song queue which automatically updates it's contents on a function call. This function call creates an ajax request to a php script which returns json data for songs in the queue (image url, song title, song author). I am then wanting to dynamically populate my ul with li's based off each of these songs returned in the json data.

The current structure is a ul containing li's which hold all the other html.

Like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="thumbnail" style="background: url('URL HERE'); background-size: 100% 100%"></div>
        <div id="songdetails">
            <div id="title">TITLE HERE</div>
            <div id="author">AUTHOR HERE</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div id="thumbnail" style="background: url('URL HERE'); background-size: 100% 100%"></div>
        <div id="songdetails">
            <div id="title">TITLE HERE</div>
            <div id="author">AUTHOR HERE</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div id="thumbnail" style="background: url('URL HERE'); background-size: 100% 100%"></div>
        <div id="songdetails">
            <div id="title">TITLE HERE</div>
            <div id="author">AUTHOR HERE</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My issue is that from what I have found on stackoverflow and other sites most people suggest something like:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('ul');

ul.appendChild(child);
```

My problem with this is that I am trying to minimize the amount of code that I am using to make the code streamline and readable and don't want to have to have variables for each child and their children.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe use templating system. the simplest one: https://mustache.github.io/

Comment: You're "trying to minimize the amount of good that [you] are using"!?

Comment: It will sure help if you will post the code which is fetching the data you want to add to the `ul`. You can easly format preformat in your `php` file the whole `html` containing all the `li` elements and then pass the `html` string in one go.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for point that out :P *code

Comment: @Franco The fetching of the data itself is irrelevant although I have added more details to the top of the OP. All I am wanting to find out is if there is a way to add that html in one go instead of defining a variable for every parent and then appending children to them.

Comment: Of course is possible, I always prefer this approach which spare me to address every single element. But as I say to help you out with this I need to see how you are getting the values. If you find this irrelevant I can not guess what is the best shut for you

Comment: Anyway as additional comment `append` is a bad idea. Because when you run the script again you will get the new data added to the old one, so you will get double items.

Comment: @Franco The OP's data is coming in as JSON; I think it's reasonable to assume it's coming in as an array of objects, where each object has the relevant data.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thanks for your comment, But what I am saying  in order to be able to help I need to see the relevant `php` file so I can let him see what can be done to get all the data in an `html` string and then output it in the `ul` element in one go.

Comment: @Franco The OP has already said that the data is coming in as JSON and thus needs to be parsed on the Javascript side into HTML, that can then be inserted into the `ul` by the Javascript. I still don't see why the PHP file is relevant. If you're asking in what format is the JSON data coming in -- is it an array of objects, is it a single object? -- I'd understand a bit better.

Comment: Ok, I know that, what I normally do is assembling all the data server side (which is faster) and just pass the complete `html` to the response. This was my proposition and not my answer. When possible I always try not to iterate through the data client-side. I hope this will be once and for all  clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery solution:

```
<ul id="container" />
```

and Javascript:

```
// Assuming the data comes in like this:
/*
[
    {url: 'http://www.example/com', title: 'Title Goes Here', author: 'Author here'},
    {url: ...
]
*/
$.getJSON('url.php', function(data) {
    $('#container').empty().append(data.map(function(x) {
        return '
            <li>
                <div id="thumbnail" style="background: url(\'' + x.url + '\'); background-size: 100% 100%"></div>
                <div id="songdetails">
                    <div id="title">' + x.title + '</div>
                    <div id="author">' + x.author + '</div>
                </div>
           </li>
        ');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do this with templating.   I create a simple templating engine that does basic string replacements like this

```
    function renderTemplate(str, obj) {
        var i, r, val, outStr=str;

        for(i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                r = new RegExp("{" + i + "}", "g");
                val = obj[i] || "&nbsp;";
                val = val.toString().replace(/^null$/, "&nbsp;");
                outStr = outStr.replace(r, val);
            }
        }

        return outStr;
    }
```

Then I'll create a template string like this

```
var template = "Hello <span class=\"name\">{name}</span> you are {age} years old";
```

Given an object that contains name and age, you can render the template to html like this

```
var html=renderTemplate(template, {name: "Alice", age: 38});
```

The keys in the object passed in in the second argument are searched in the template wrapped in curly braces ("{" and "}")

Lastly, I create a new element and set this string to the innerHTML and append it to my document

```
var newLI = document.createElement("li");
newLI.innerHTML = html;
ulNode.appendChild(newLI);
```

this renderTemplate is an early creation of mine and I have new versions burried in code that are more fault tolerant, but this is an ok example.

Note:  There are other templating solutions in the wild.   This is my home grown one.   As a comment on your OP said, Mustache is one such.